# iPad Remote Debugging

Tags: ipad, ios6, remote-debugging

I want to debug my webapp remotely. I have an iPad-3, iOS-6 and a MacBook. So I tried two scenarios.

A) I can use remote debugging, if I save my webapp on my home-screen. Unfortunately I am not able to clear the cache!

B) I can use safari on iPad and visit my website (= my webapp). If I switch to my MacBook-screen and visit 'Entwickler'-Tab (German for developer-tab), iPad-entry shows up, but there is a warning message, that there is no debbuggable application on my iPad ('keine überprüfbare Programme'). I enabled remote debugging on my iPad-safari-configuration as far as I know.

What can I do now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried rebooting your iPad/force closed Safari App after checking your remote debug setting? (not kidding, i reboot mine once in 2-3 months or so and had the same problem once..)

Comment: I rebooted my iPad - nothing changed.

Comment: UPDATE: strange ... I tried it with another iPad and remote debugging works like expected! How can I detect the differences?

Comment: NEXT UPDATE: I solved it - you are not allowed to use private surf mode in safari options.

Comment: NEXT UPDATE: moreover iPad-safari must have focus and must be awake.

Comment: Thanks man, the private surf mode is what solved it for me, once deactivated, it suddenly worked.

Comment: I wrote an answer that the solution gets more visible to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above - disable private surf mode in your iPad settings and take care that your iPad is awake.